# PLEASE - Blue boxes + ? instead of the images in my Android + Phonegap App, how to fix?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

In my Android App the  tags seam to be broken resulting in a blue box with a question mark instead of images. It only happens on some devices, and works fine on an iPhone. PLEASE, can anyone help me work out how to fix this? All the images are there, and work fine in the emulator and on my test Android 'phone.

[image]

Comment: Those are broken images. You probably just goofed up the URL to them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the images are under assets/www in the file hierarchy.